# Host an Angular app in OpenLiteSpee Web Server

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, openlitespeed

I am trying to host my angular app into my OpenLiteSpeed but I am not getting anything.

To create the app for production I use: ng build --prod, automatically it creates all the files I need in the dist folder.

Next, I move all these files to my root folder on the server.

Finally, I check if the webpage is working but it doesn't shows anything just the blank page!

The HTML code for the index is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ConFusion</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.c3adc567aae88948c2ab.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.acf0dec4155e77772545.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills.35a5ca1855eb057f016a.js" defer></script><script src="main.9a959de356bd26498a0e.js" defer></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does any error shown from the browser console?

Comment: Yes, it throws me: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, It already works! I just needed to rebuild the app in Angular (ng build --prod) because the older files was affecting the development of the new app, thanks to your comment I could detect this issue! Again, Thank you so much for your comment!

Comment: Glad to know that you managed to fix the issue.